# The acceptedAnswer property is not recognized by the schema (for example, schema.org) for objects of type FAQPage

Tags: html, schema

when i want to create schema faq i got error like this :
"The acceptedAnswer property is not recognized by the schema (for example, schema.org) for objects of type FAQPage."
why i got this error ?

this is my example code

```
 <div itemtype="https://schema.org/Question"  itemscope="true" itemprop="mainEntity" class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                     <h2 itemprop="name" class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn faq-button btn-link collapsed"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                           Apa itu Asuransi Kesehatan?
                           <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/new-style/kesehatan/assets/img/icons/Down.svg" style="float:right;max-width:24px;" />
                        </button>
                     </h2>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" itemscope="true" itemprop="acceptedAnswer"  itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                     <div itemprop="text" class="card-body">
                        Sebuah jenis produk asuransi yang secara khusus menjamin biaya kesehatan atau perawatan para anggota asuransi tersebut jika mereka jatuh sakit atau mengalami kecelakaan. Secara garis besar ada dua jenis perawatan yang ditawarkan perusahaan-perusahaan asuransi, yaitu Rawat Inap dan Rawat Jalan.
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
```